# Does Hierarchical Partitioning in Parquet Prevent Partition Pruning on Specific Levels?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I'm working with a dataset partitioned by year and month in a Parquet file structure. The original partitioning was done hierarchically:

`dbfs:/FileStorage/airlines/Year=1988/Month=12`

However, it was later changed to a single partitioning level:

`dbfs:/FileStorage/airlines/YearMonth=1998-12`

What could be the reason for this change in partitioning strategy? Specifically, does the hierarchical partitioning scheme (Year/Month) prevent partition pruning on the month level, or are there any performance or usability considerations that might lead to this redefinition? Any insights into the potential advantages or disadvantages of each approach would be appreciated.

Comment: which Databricks environment is it?  are the dbfs entries mounts to external adls storage? more depth == slower perf on adls gen2 to start queries for example.